# How to make a video from frames in Android

Tags: android, video, video-capture

I have an app that uses some image processing on the video stream. For each frame I capture from the camera, I send the frame to my code (NDK) and get a byte array back with the frame processed.

I would like to take that processed frame stream and create a small video from it (about 20 frames a second for 5 seconds). I'd like to save the video to the gallery or as a file in the file system.

How is it possible?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Comment: Thanks - But I already got all my code working, just need to save the processed stream to a video.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693305/converting-byte-array-to-video-file may help you.

Comment: Many thanks! It's almost there - I think that I need to somehow transform the byte[] stream to a video stream - any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but I think creating a `FileOutputStream` into a new `File` passing your `byte[]` would do the job. Something like the example in that link I gave you.

Comment: OK, tried that - it didn't work :) writing the frame stream to a file is not making a working mp4 file. I guess something is missing?

Comment: Not that I know. I'm sorry I couldn't help you. Hope someone answer you properly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mediaCodec Encoder API introduced in android 4.3 to do the recording easily.
refer to this class to get started

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html